# Canonical metric when $-K_X$ is nef?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, moduli-space

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variery. Let $-K_X$ be nef , then which type of Canonical metric In the sense of Einstein type metric is suitable for it.

In fact when $K_X$ or $-K_X$ is ample WE know that WE have $ Ric(\omega)=-\omega$, and $ Ric(\omega)=\omega$,  when X is K-stable.

In my opinion when $-K_X$ be nef then WE know that the Albanese map is surjective, I.e $\pi:X\to Alb(X)$ is surjective and the best Canonical metric is the relative Kahler Einstein metric along Albanese map $$Ric_{X/S}(\omega)=-\xi(s)\omega$$
As soon as the relative tangent sheaf $T_{X/S}$ is stable In the sense of Mumford.

Where here $S=Alb(X)$ is Albanese variety  and $\omega$ is the relative Kahler form and $\xi(s)$ is fiberwise constant.

In this case the right flow is the following Hyperbolic Relative Kahler Ricci flow.

$$\frac{\partial^2\omega}{\partial s'\partial t}=-Ric_{X/S}\omega(s',t)-\xi(s)\omega_{s'}(t)$$

Where here $s'=\frac{1}{s}$ and $s\to 0$

See here the definition of relative Kahler form see my answer to this post
[What is a Kählerian variety?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618399/what-is-a-k%C3%A4hlerian-variety/2574988#2574988)

Also about Albanese map see my answer to this post
[What is the Albanese map good for?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205316/what-is-the-albanese-map-good-for/2576878#2576878)

For nef Line bundle see my answer to this post 
[nef Line bundles over Kähler manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850372/nef-line-bundles-over-k%C3%A4hler-manifolds/2578897#2578897)

When Tangent sheaf of a Fano Variery is nef see JPD paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03725

My motivation is that let $\pi:X\to \Delta$  be a surjective holomorphic fibre space from a projective variery to a holomorphic disc.

Let $K_{X_t}$ is ample then the Canonical divisor $K_{X_0}$ is nef and finding a type of Canonical metric on central fiber is an open question and it may admits several différent type of Canonical metrics including twisted KE

See my post about Beauville-Bogomolov decomposition by using relative Kahler Ricci flow along Albanese map [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277561/kähler-ricci-flow-approach-for-beauville-bogomolov-type-decomposition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277561/k%C3%A4hler-ricci-flow-approach-for-beauville-bogomolov-type-decomposition)

Hassan Jolany